# Red Hat lvm logical volume size parameters

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I am trying to find where it is documented that I can determine for certain what the bB and sS options are in lvcreate and lvextend commands from lvm> prompt (or for that matter from # prompt).  The man pages do not seem to describe these particular options.  I suspect it is blocks and sectors, but then why the upper and lower case ?  This is what I found online (below), but it doesn't answer the question about the first four size 'suffixes'.  Does anyone have a specific document reference ?  I'm using RHEL 6.9.

> ```
>   -L, --size LogicalVolumeSize[bBsSkKmMgGtTpPeE]
>     Gives the size to allocate for the new logical volume. A size suffix of K for kilobytes, M for megabytes, G for gigabytes, T for
> ```
>
> terabytes, P for petabytes or E for exabytes is optional.
>           Default unit is megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'bB and sS' but rather 'b'/'B' or 's'/'S'.  They are individual single-letter options in lvcreate.  Other areas of the documentation refer to it as such: [b|B|s|S|k|K|m|M|g|G].

To quote the documentation:

> A size suffix of **B for bytes, S for sectors as 512 bytes**, K for kilobytes, M for megabytes, G for gigabytes,  T for terabytes, P for petabytes or E for exabytes is optional.              Default unit is megabytes.

As for the lower versus upper case, since version 2.02.54 (October 2009), the tools distinguish between powers of 1024 bytes (e.g. KiB, MiB, GiB) and powers of 1000 bytes (e.g. KB, MB, GB) **if si_unit_consistency is set to 1**.

You can see in this diff when the change was introduced.
https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/commit/bce3ac2c73b07460ed49c4f22ec1d04c6fcd4d19. You'll note that the lowercase is base 1024 and the upper-case is base 1000 *if* si_unit_consistency in */etc/lvm/lvm.conf* is set to 1.

Irrespective of the setting or case it is written in, both 's' and 'S' is 512 byte sectors and bytes are always bytes, irrespective of 'b' or 'B'.  Only when kilo/mega/giga/tera/peta/exta come into play are we multiplying by 1000-vs-1024.

Comment: I had assumed the lower/upper were different but after testing this, you are correct; two volumes created with 990M and 990m have exactly the same number of blocks.  Good complete answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to be even more complete after reviewing the source code.  The setting in lvm.conf actually determines which behaviour happens.  It just so happens your setting is keeping them the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing in a lot of man pages but included on https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/lvcreate.html

> ```
>    -L|--size LogicalVolumeSize[b|B|s|S|k|K|m|M|g|G|t|T|p|P|e|E]
>           Gives the size to allocate for the new logical volume.  A size suffix of B for bytes, S for sectors  as
>           512 bytes, K for kilobytes, M for megabytes, G for gigabytes, T for terabytes, P for petabytes or E for
>           exabytes is optional.
>           Default unit is megabytes.
> ```

Comment: This is a good answer (helpful) but it still leaves me wondering the distinction between upper and lower case, specifically for the B and S options.  I assume that k vs K is 1000 vs 1024, but this doesn't make sense in S & B context.  That being said I wonder if there is any difference between b and B.

Comment: You could verify it in the sourcecode